# Can zombies spawn in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My nether portal in the overworld is light up and gated to prevent mobs entering/leaving, but I recently was attacked by 10 or more zombies when I entered the nether. No skeletons, creepers or spiders.

Could it be a glitch where the pigmen are spawning as zombies? I killed 4 pigmen before the zombies appeared, and 2 were wondering the area after I slaughtered the hoard.

A big wave of pigmen with a single zombie attacked. Then a zombie villager appeared behind me in my small pigman hunting lodge which contains the portal. A couple more zombies appeared outside. This happened twice but the second time there were more zombies and less pigmen in the initial wave. I also had another wave without a zombie in my bunker.

I think it might be an event like the zombie hoards that attack villages.

Zombies have been dropping from higher platforms that can't be accessed from the portal platform and I have stayed close to the bunker so I doubt they have been coming through it. Especially because there has not been a single skeleton, creeper or spider.

Update.
I just saw a zombie spawn beside a pigman in a lit area. I had not hit any pigmen yet.

Snocrach also said:

> > Zombie pigmen can summon their zombie friends from the overworld to help
> >     them fight the forces of evil.
> >
> > this is a normal minecraft feature - nothing to do with the world generation.

I am playing the Snocrash's Hermit Chunk Challenge in 1.9

Comment: Was the portal blocked off?, some mobs can come through to and from the Nether.

Comment: @hyperviper11 At the time the portal was completely blocked off. I have recently moved this forward and placed a torch on the ground so that I can move out of the portal before breaking through the wall. It also has a roof.

Comment: That is very odd. Perhaps some information can be gathered at this site: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Zombie. Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you checked your last sentence? I mean if this thing does not modify your world somehow into this behaviour.

Comment: @Antoine Hejlík It should be vanilla other than the hermit chunking, but I can't guarantee that. I will try asking Snocrash.

Comment: @rom016 If it is some custom map or so, you still can have some hidden commandblocks spawning those, that was in my mind. However i don't know how this Challenge differs from normal game, if it is different by some settings or it is predefined map etc :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this issue is fixed, but Zombie Pigmen can or could spawn [Zombie reinforcements](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Reinforcements) when attacked. It was intended that they would spawn Zombie Pigmen as reinforcements, but since the code is kind of related, I believe that could happen. It's possible that's still a thing in 1.9.

Comment: This sounds quite likely as the first wave of zombies was often around 4 and appeared after attacking pigmen.

Comment: I believe this is true as I saw a zombie spawn as I struck the hoard in front of me. I hope I can use this to spawn some zombie villagers. Preferable a farmer and a priest I am rolling in rotten flesh.

Answer (score 2):

It is strange, but Zombies **can actually spawn in the Nether**, possibly due to a bug or intended coding.

But it is very odd that there were 10 Zombies. Zombies rarely spawn in the Nether, and **only if you get "lucky" there will spawn 4 at once.**

**Probably that multiple groups spawned** (this happens very rarely), and the Zombie Villager spawned because of the 5% chance for a Zombie to become its Zombie Villager counterpart.

Also, **additional Zombies could have spawned due to the Zombie Reinforcement feature**, which means that if you hit a Zombie, others may spawn and head to attack you.